# Installing OpenCV: didn't specify number of cores in CMake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm a programming student and it's my first time using OpenCV and Linux. So after configuring the installation of OpenCV with CMake, I didn't specify the cores by putting in `make -j4`. I'm installing the OpenCV on Nvidea Jetson Nano and it's taking forever. Will this affect the usage of OpenCV after installation? I do not know much about this, so sorry if I sound ignorant.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in the man pages. Type `man make` and scroll down to see, what the -j option does. Here is an excerpt:

> -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs] Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously. If there is more than one -j option, the last one
>   is effective. If the -j option is given without an argument, make will
>   not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.

This option is purely for the simultaneous compilation of OpenCV itself, it will NOT affect the usage after compilation.